# Is there a way to simplify this linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 bool flags and need to filter my collection accordingly.  There has to be an cleaner way to do this.  If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

```
var _filteredEvents = from ev in _events 
                      select ev;
if (!queueEmail) // don't queue email
{
    if (!queueTextMessaging) // don't queue textmessaging
    {
        _filteredEvents = from ev in _events
                              where ev.QueueTypeEnumText != QueueType.TextMessage.ToString() 
                                && ev.QueueTypeEnumText !=QueueType.Email.ToString()
                              select ev;
    }
    else
    {
         _filteredEvents = from ev in _events
                              where ev.QueueTypeEnumText != QueueType.Email.ToString()
                              select ev;
    }
}
else //queue email
{
    if (!queueTextMessaging) //don't queue textmessaging
    {
        _filteredEvents = from ev in _events
                          where ev.QueueTypeEnumText != QueueType.TextMessage.ToString()
                          select ev;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since LINQ uses deferred execution, you can just change the `Where()` extensions onto your object, and reassign it as you go:

```
var _filteredEvents = _events; 
if (!queueEmail)
     _filteredEvents =  _filteredEvents.Where(ev => ev.QueueTypeEnumText != QueueType.Email.ToString());
if (!queueTextMessaging)
     _filteredEvents =  _filteredEvents.Where(ev => ev.QueueTypeEnumText != QueueType.TextMessage.ToString());
```

Comment: Can someone elaborate on this a little bit? I am interested. How exactly is this working. Maybe I don't fully understand deferred execution. A brief explanation would be splendid. Maybe just walk me through each line and explain what's happening. Is the second `IF` adding a `.Where()` to the `.Where()` that is already there from the first `IF`? I was under the impression you couldn't assign a generic `var` after it had been initialized.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks! I did get an error because I was using a strongly typed collection so I updated line 1 to "_events.AsEnumerable()" and it went away. Error was "Cannot implicitly convert type.
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable..."

Comment: @Chevex: You can reassign to a "var" - but you can't change it's type.  If the original var is `IEnumerable<T>`, then you can assign "over it" as much as you'd like.  By calling _filteredEvents.Where(), we return a new `IEnumerable<T>`, and just replace the reference in _filteredEvents.  This can be done as many times as you want, since the execution of the "query" doesn't actually occur until you enumerate the collection.  This means, when we finally do the enumeration (after the above code), all of the where clauses will get executed as well as the original "select" if its required.

Answer (score 2):

You can make one where clause:

```
where 
     (queueTextMessaging || ev.QueueTypeEnumText != QueueType.TextMessage.ToString())
   &&(queueEmail || ev.QueueTypeEnumText !=QueueType.Email.ToString())
```

Comment: Thanks Mark! You and Jon had the same idea. Both were useful to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
var _filteredEvents =
  from ev in _events where (
    queueTextMessaging || ev.QueueTypeEnumText != QueueType.TextMessage.ToString() &&
    queueEmail || ev.QueueTypeEnumText !=QueueType.Email.ToString())
  select ev;
```

Comment: I really like this solution as well. Thanks Jon!

Answer (score 0):

I would simply create a Method testing the condition for you

`var _filteredEvents = from ev in _events 
                          where Test(queueEmail, queueTextMessaging, ev) 
                        select ev;`

...

`bool Test(bool foo, bool bar, Event ev) {...}`